# How to get do binary operations on the Nth byte in my varbinary column?

Tags: sql, binary, mariadb

I've been able to get the Nth byte out of the field with `substring(colname, N, 1)`, but at that point it seems impossible to treat the result as binary:

```
> select substring(colname, N, 1) from [...]
\
> select hex(substring(colname, N, 1)) from [...]
5C
> select hex(substring(colname, N, 1) & 0xff) from [...]
0
> select cast(substring(colname, N, 1) as unsigned integer) from [...]
0
```

Compared to:

```
> select cast(0x5c as binary);
\
> select hex(0x5c & 0xff);
5C
> select cast(0x5c as unsigned integer);
92
```

---

What I want to end up with is something like this:

```
> select [...] where substring(colname, N, 1) & 0b00100000 = 0b00100000;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like that:

```
select ascii(substring(colname,N,1)) from [...]
```

Comment: You need code of your Nth character to work with it. Function ascii(..) returns code of character.